# 「1」から「指定された数」までの数列を配列で作りたい

Tags: javascript, array

## 目的

数を指定して関数に渡します。
そうすると配列が作られて、1,2,3,4と順に配列に組み込まれていきます。
指定された数になるとその数が代入されてそこで止まり、配列が返されると思っていました。

よろしくお願いします。

## 原始コード

```js
const createNum = (maxNum) => {
const ary_result = [];
for (let index = 1; index < maxNum; index++) {
    ary_result.push(index);
    if (index === maxNum) {
        return ary_result;
    }
}
};
console.log(createNum(100));

//result
// [1,2,3, ... ,100] となるはずだった
```

Comment: for 文で `index < maxNum` としているので `index` が `maxNum` と等しくなることはありません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (let index = 1; index < maxNum; index++)
```

のループ内の処理が実行されるのは`index`が`maxNum`未満の場合です。このため、次のロジックが実行されません。

```
    if (index === maxNum) {
        return ary_result;
    }
```

for文を次のように変更し、

```
for (let index = 1; index <= maxNum; index++)
```

ループの終了時に復帰(`return ary_result;`)すればよいです。

```js
const createNum = (maxNum) => {
    const ary_result = [];
    for (let index = 1; index <= maxNum; index++) {
        ary_result.push(index);
    }
    return ary_result;
};
console.log(createNum(100));
```

Answer (score 4):

ちなみにJavaScriptには[ジェネレーター関数](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)というものがあり、呼び出し毎に新たな値を返すことができます。また、[スプレッド構文](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)というものがあり、反復可能オブジェクトから配列を構築することができます。両者を組み合わせることで、ものすごくシンプルに実現できます。

```js
function* createNum(maxNum) {
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= maxNum)
        yield i++;
}
console.log([...createNum(100)]);
```

Answer (score -3):

## 回答ではありません

ここまでのコードを何となく計測して、最後にArrayにサイズを指定して生成してみました。

```js
function* gen_createNum(maxNum) {
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= maxNum)
    yield i++;
}
const measure = (f, args) => {
  const s = new Date();
  const result = f(...args);
  console.log(new Date() - s);
  return result;
};
const creators = [
  (maxNum) => {
    const ary_result = [];
    for (let index = 1; index <= maxNum; index++) {
      ary_result.push(index);
    }
    return ary_result;
  },
  (maxNum) => [...gen_createNum(maxNum)],
  (maxNum) => {
    const ary_result = new Array(maxNum);
    for (let index = 0; index < maxNum; ++index) {
      ary_result[index] = index + 1;
    }
    return ary_result;
  },
];
const results = creators.map((f) => measure(f, [1024 * 1024 * 16]));
```

### 手元での実行結果

ちなみにWindows Firefox 110.0 64bitというありふれた環境ですが。。。

```
297
2799
270
```

同PCのvbox Ubuntu上のnode v16.18.0だと

```
408
1484
103
```

ですね。

### 追記

こんなに技術的に有為なことなのに**なぜかコメントもなくマイナス評価**なので、k勝手ながら皆様の貧弱な環境で動作しないのではないかと思い、多少サイズを控えめにしてみました。

Comment: コメントで回答の仕方や投票の方針などの議論が続いています。
こういったコメントはただ削除されることもありますが、今回は分量もあるので[チャットに移動](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150092/discussion-on-answer-by-dameo-1)しました。
Q&Aの技術的な面でなく、このサイト自体の運営にまつわる疑問や議論は[メタサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)で行なって下さい。
メタサイトに関しては[『「メタ」とは？どのように機能しますか？ 』](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)をご覧下さい。